# How to use FirebaseFunctions and log events or errors?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Since there's only documentation for Node.js, it's unclear of how to use FirebaseFunctions Swift library. I will appreciate if someone can provide some basic examples.

Comment: You cannot write the cloud functions in Swift -- they have to be written in a Node.js language (Javascript, Typescript). However, you can *call* them from your Swift program and there is documentation showing how to do this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function

Comment: Correct @jnpdx. What you *can* do though is *call* your Cloud Functions from Swift, as shown in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#swift_1. So: 1) Write your Cloud Functions in Node.js, 2) Call them from any of the client side SDKs mentioned in that documentation link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jnpdx pointed out in their comment, Firebase only support writing Callable Cloud Functions in Node.js.

What you *can* do though is *call* your Cloud Functions from Swift, as shown in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#swift_1):

```
functions.httpsCallable("addMessage").call(["text": inputField.text]) { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
    // ...
  }
  if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any], let text = data["text"] as? String {
    self.resultField.text = text
  }
}
```

And to handle errors:

```
if let error = error as NSError? {
  if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
    let message = error.localizedDescription
    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
  }
  // ...
}
```

So it's usually a two-step process:

1. Write your Cloud Functions in Node.js.
2. Call them from any of the client side SDKs mentioned in that documentation link

See also the examples in the [Firebase Functions Swift QuickStart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/functions) (thanks to [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556617/paul-beusterien) for sharing that link).

Answer (score 1):

See also the examples in the [Firebase Functions Swift QuickStart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/functions)

Comment: Hey Paul. Thanks for the link. This answer is unlikely to do well on its own, due to its link-only nature. Do you mind if I copy it into my answer, so that more people are likely to see it??

Comment: Good idea! Thanks puf!